# jquery throbber for 1.5.2

Tags: jquery-plugins

I set out to use the ui.throbber.js plugin with 1.5.2. It doesn't officially have a 1.5.2 version, and, in fact, the version available isn't working. No throbber appears, and no errors in the Chrome console, and inspect-element shows that the javascript has run and done the surgery on the div.

I just want to start a spinner going at 'ready' and stop it when we hear back from a web service. Can someone suggest an alternative to ui.throbber.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a version of ui.throbber.js that workswith 1.5.2, but I did find an alternative that will work for 1.5.2.  Try nimbleLoader.

https://github.com/nimbleapps/jquery-nimble-loader

I've tested it under my 1.5.2 environment and it works and provides essentially the same result.